# C printf integer type U32

Tags: c, integer, printf

I have the hex value `0x5a800000000b` and I'm trying to get a printf statement in C to print it to the console.

So far (because I'm useless in C) I'm able to get the 'b' to print, using the syntax:

```
printf("Hex value%x\n", value);
```

The value is stored in an integer type U32, but after trying all different combinations of %llx, %lx, I just keep getting compiler warnings.

I'm guessing that I'm getting the printf syntax wrong, but I can't seem to find the right % option, can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `%ulx` or `%ullx`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a problem with the `printf`.

The problem is that a 32 bits variable cannot hold the value `0x5a800000000b`. 32 bits can hold only 8 hex digits: 0x0000000b. Hence the `b` on output.

To store such a large value, you should use a 64 bits variable.

```
long long value = 0x5a800000000bLL
```

Note also the double `L` at the end. It tells the compiler that the constant is also a `long long`.

Then you can use `%llx` in the `printf` format string.

Comment: Ahh yes, of course!  I was getting so preoccupied with the printf, I forgot to check how big the actual value was :)  Thanks Didier!

Answer (score 4):

There are some pre-defined macro for these types:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
int64_t PRId64. PRIi64
int32_t PRId32, PRIi32
int16_t PRId16, PRIi16
int8_t PRId8, PRIi8
```

For example:

```
printf("%"PRId32"\n", my32Int);
```

Comment: Oops, it should be PRId64. Thanks!

Comment: Although this question is C and there are no problems using the inttypes macros this way in C, it's probably good practice to include spaces between these macros and string literals due to the way the preprocessor works in C++. Without any space the preprocessor will not apply the inttypes macros because it will instead identify it as a use of a user defined literal.

Answer (score 0):

The value 0x5a800000000b is more that 32 bits, so you have to use a `long`.

```
long value = 0x5a800000000bl;
printf("Hex value%lx\n", value);
```

Note that hex constant should end in `l`,.

Comment: @dbrank0 - depends on the compiler/environment.

Comment: To be independent of the platform, just use `uint64_t` in such cases.